# PostBack With a Label?

Tags: .net, asp.net

I know this has to be an easy question; but I haven't been able to find a solution online.  I'm new to ASP.Net and I'm trying to trigger a PostBack when the user clicks on a Text link.

I tried using the HyperLink control, with runat="server"; but it doesn't have a Click event.  If I set the URL to my page and include a querystring value (like ?test=a) it will reload my page, but `IsPostBack` will be false.

I know I can do this with buttons, but I prefer the look of a text link.

What should I be using?

EDIT:  Thanks for the responses.  Sorry for asking such a silly question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a control called`LinkButton` - it is a button that looks like a hyperlink.

They are described here on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Try using `LinkButton` control. It has click event. ([MSDN Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton%28v=VS.100%29.aspx))

Answer (score 0):

You can indeed use a [LinkButton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) as others pointed before me.

In general you can trigger a postback on any control by generating javascript postback code - using "ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference()" method;

for example you can use this code to cause postback on javascript event :

`YourControl.Attributes.Add("onmousedown",Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(YourControl,"onmousedown"));`